# Qt Creator 2.8.1 ROS and Catkin problems

Tags: ros, qt, qtcreator, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64-bit, Hydro, Qt 5.1.1, and Qt Creator 2.8.1.

I have been working on some wet ROS packages using Qt Creator without a hitch when using Qt Creator 2.4.1 and Qt 4.8 from Ubuntu's software center. However, I want to take advantage of some of the nice new openGL helper functions in Qt 5.1 so I installed it alongside 4.8. I also installed the latest version of Qt Creator (2.8.1) as recommended by that community.

Qt Creator 2.8.1 is working great for non-ROS projects using a .pro file. But when I try to open ROS package from a CMakeLists.txt I get a few weird problems that I'm not sure how to fix. I'll walk you through what happens.

I open my catkin workspace using CMakeLists.txt: 
`$ /opt/qtcreator-2.8.1/bin/qtcreator sandbox/src/CMakeLists.txt`

With Qt Creator 2.4.1, the build directory auto-populates with something like /sandbox/qt-build and I would simply change it to /sandbox/build. However, with 2.8.1 the auto-populated build directory is "/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake-build". So I switch it to "/sandbox/build".

Then I press next and Run CMake. CMake executes with no errors, just as I would expect it to. 
 
`-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pwn/sandbox/build`

I Click finish, and get the following error: 
 
**"Cannot create file /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake.user: Permission denied"**

After click finish, the project is populated with a bunch of catkin nonsense, but none of my actual ROS packages.

I then get two popup windows with the following error: 
**"Cannot create file /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake.user: Permission denied"**

Has anyone else run into any of these sorts of issues with the newer version of Qt Creator? Have you found any solutions?

For now I am just using Qt Creator 2.4.1 and it continues to work well, but I would love to have only one version on my computer that works for ROS and other projects.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91516/qt-creator-2.8.1-ros-and-catkin-problems/) by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following worked for me with qtcreator 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) with ROS Indigo

Within your `src` directory, check which file the symlink `CMakeLists.txt` points to. In my case (Indigo on Trusty), `ls -l` tells me:

> `CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake`

Then replace the symlink with a copy of `toplevel.cmake`:

> `rm CMakeLists.txt`

> `cp /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake CMakeLists.txt`

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-12-05**:
Doing that...are you sure you don't mess up your system?
I have the same problem with the same version of Qt Creator.
There a way to undo those operation of QtCreator doesn't run?

**Comment by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on 2014-12-05**:
I have been applying this fix to my workspaces and it doesn't seem to mess up my system at all. Not sure about the answer to your second question

**Comment by [feixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/23311/feixiao/) on 2015-12-21**:
I try, it works!!thank you! but can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i have problems with qt.

when i press RUN it can not RUN please help me

if u need my TeamViewer tell me

---

Originally posted by [samouel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23505/samouel/) with karma: 11 on 2015-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1